# How to get the column with smallest value from column with regards to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql server table which looks like this:-

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC-123 | 444 |
| ABC-123 | 555 |
| ABC-123 | 666 |
| ABC-222 | 552 |
| ABC-222 | 111 |
| ABC-222 | 552 |

How do I get data from this table with unique values from Column1 and the smallest value from Column two?

So a valid result for the above data would look like:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC-123 | 444 |
| ABC-222 | 111 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jens `select DISTINCT Column1, Column2 from MyTable` but this of course does not bring me the smallest value from the second column and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Presumably you looked at [`MIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) so why wasn't that suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using WITH TIES**

```
 Select top 1 with ties *
  From  YourTable
  Order By row_number() over (partition by Column1 order by Column2)
```

**Or a Nudge more Performant**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN = row_number() over (partition by Column1 order by Column2) 
      From  YourTable
)
Select *
 From  cte
 Where RN=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select Column1, min(Column2) from table group by column1
```

should do the job

Comment: Zoomed right past that one  :)  +1